# Using redux in React inside Aurelia framework

Tags: reactjs, redux, aurelia

I am using Aurelia framework for my client app.
However, for a particular reason, I used react for some screens.
Implementing redux in the client app, I found it very complicated since the redux is already used in react parts.
Does anybody know how to use the same store with react and aurelia?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well nothing hinders you from using the same store within Aurelia. [Here's a blog post of mine](https://www.sitepoint.com/managing-state-aurelia-with-redux/) of using Redux in general with Aurelia, and it contains a sample like this:

```
import marked from 'marked';
import { bindable } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { createStore } from 'redux';

export class MarkdownRedux {
  @bindable raw;
  html = '';
  store = createStore(textUpdater);
```

as you can see in the line above it essentially creates a new store at this moment. So instead of that you should just obtain a reference to your previously created and exported store from React.

```
  constructor() {
    this.store.subscribe(this.update.bind(this));
  }

  update() {
    const state = this.store.getState();
    this.html = state.html;
    this.raw = state.raw;
  }

  keyupHandler(newValue) {
    this.store.dispatch(updateText(newValue));
  }

  attached() {
    this.keyupHandler(this.raw);
  }
}
```

below of that it's all just the same dispatching and obtaining of states as usual.